# Get Row with Closest Value

Tags: python, pandas

in pandas I want to introduce a new column 'Neighbor' in my dataframe which saves (e.g.) the index or the value of another row, for which a certain column B is most close to the value of the current row.
E.g.

```
   A   Neighbor
0  5   1
1  4   0
2  1   3
3  2   2
4  10  0
```

Do you know a pandas function doing that? As my dataset is very big apply unfortunately is too slow.

Thanks!

Comment: If you sort the entire list (A), can you just perform .shift() on the index? You might need to store the index as a column to get the shift function to pull it out this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
df['myindex']  = df.index
# result = df.sort(['A'])
result = df.sort_values(by='A')
result['NeighborIndex'] = result['myindex'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: From the Docs:
kind : {‘quicksort’, ‘mergesort’, ‘heapsort’}, default ‘quicksort’
Choice of sorting algorithm. See also ndarray.np.sort for more information. mergesort is the only stable algorithm. For DataFrames, this option is only applied when sorting on a single column or label.

Comment: Sorting first might avoid an n^2 worst case type runtime, unless you can get some optimization that does the sorting for you or can scan an unsorted list without a performance hit

Comment: if you're in the 100's of millions of rows you might consider doing this in a DB or something?

Comment: I have just been thinking, what if I have 3 columns A, B and and sort according A, B. Now for my neighbor calculation I want the nearest value of column C, but the category of B, so the value of B, should be, e.g. 1 different than the element I am calculating the neighbor for? How would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

IDK, whether you check my update answer for your previous question or not, this is the way I am using

```
a=df.A.values[:,None]-df.A.values
np.fill_diagonal(a, 9999999)
np.argmin(abs(a),0)
Out[1160]: array([1, 0, 3, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just saw! This works and is interesting, but I fear it is still a bit slow and "hacky" ... cool though and would work.

Comment: @Gemini if you think numpy is slow........you can try it ...numpy always faster than pandas.